# Product space, product and uniform topology -- open sets?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, uniform-convergence, infinite-product

Consider a countable product of (compact) spaces $X= \Pi_{j\in J}X_j$. Let it have the uniform topology. An open ball in $X$ is then given by

$$B^u_\epsilon(x):=\{x'\in X: \sup_{j\in J}d(x_j,x'_j)<\epsilon \}$$

We know that the uniform topology is strictly finer than the product topology on $X$.

My question is how to represent any given open ball $B^u_\epsilon$ in terms of open balls that are open also in the product topology?

Comment: Your question is not obvious for me, could you explain it again

Comment: I thought that for example we can represent $B_\epsilon^u(x)$ as a countable intersection of the sets that are open in the product topology?

Comment: You ought to be able to devise a countable intersection to achieve your desired result using projections, but I'm not certain. This is what seems natural to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $j\in J$ and $\delta>0$ let $U_j(\delta)=\{x'\in X:d_j(x_j,x_j')<\delta\}$; these sets are open in the product topology. For $\delta>0$ let $B(\delta)=\bigcap_{j\in J}U_j(\delta)$; these sets are open in the box topology. Then

$$B_\epsilon^u(x)=\bigcup_{0<\delta<\epsilon}B(\delta)=\bigcup_{0<\delta<\epsilon}\bigcap_{j\in J}U_j(\delta)\;.$$

Comment: Thank you! But just for clarification, should not that be that for product open $U_j(\delta)=\{x'\in X: d_j(x_j,x'_j)<\delta\}$ for $j\in J^f$ where $J^f$ is a set of finitely many indices?

Comment: @Cactusenok: I don’t need to use all of the product basic open sets; it’s sufficient here (and easier) to look at single indices.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, it not because take $(0,1)^J$ where is $J$ any set. Note it is open in unform metric which is not open that product

Comment: Not sure your set is open in the uniform (it is open in the box topology). However, my question is different -- given open set in the uniform topology does there always exists some representation in terms of the sets that would be open in the product topology